# vsim command in Questasim for test pass/fail information

Tags: system-verilog, questasim

Is the pass/fail test information for the Questa simulation recorded in the .ucdb file? If so is there a `vsim` command that extracts that information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
coverage attribute -name TESTSTATUS
```